# Where does the READ Syscall output, and where to find documentation?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian

I'm currently on a school project in ARM assembly on a pi (raspbian 32) and I'm testing out the prof's code to make sure it works. here's what he provided:

```
_sInput:
    PUSH {r1-r2, lr}        @ preserve values for function
    MOV r0, #STDIN          @ set the input to the console
    MOV r7, #READ           @ set the syscall to READ
    SWI 0                   @ make the syscall
    POP {r1-r2, lr}         @ restore values sent to function

sInputStrStart:
    CMP r2, #0              @ memory bounds checker
    MOVLE r0, #0            @ if no more characters put null in R1
    STRLEB r0, [r1]         @ if no more chars store null in array
    BLE sInputEnd           @ if no more chars exit
    LDRB r0, [r1]           @ load in the next byte of sent array
    CMP r0, #10             @ check for newline character
    MOVEQ r0, #0            @ if end put null character in R1
    STRB r0, [r1], #1       @ write byte out at end of array 1
    SUB r2, r2, #1          @ decrement letter counter
    BNE sInputStrStart      @ loop until newline

sInputEnd:
    MOV pc, lr              @ return to calling environment
```

Here's what I wrote:

```
.global _start

.equ STDOUT, 1
.equ WRITE, 4

_start:
    LDR r1, =input
    MOV r2, #21
    BL _sInput
    
    MOV r0, #STDOUT
    MOV r7, #WRITE
    SWI 0
    
_end:
    MOV r7, #1
    SWI 0
    
.data

input: .space 21
```

Now here are my questions. First, where does the READ syscall output? The prof keeps r1-r2 safe by temporarily putting them on the stack, but I thought READ wrote the input in R1. I'm trying to run the code, but I can't seem to print it which leaves me to believe that I'm not using the input correctly. How can I access the information stored with read?

Second, I looked up online and tried to find some documentation as well as "man syscall", but to no avail. Is there some place that can tell me how it works? For instance, r0 has to be equal to 1 for it to take a standard output. I know this simply from reading others code. Is there some place that can tell me "ya put a 1 in r0 for stdin, a 2 for ..."? Whenever we used to program in any other language, finding documentation that would tell you how to use a certain function was easy. Now, it feels like acquiring super secret government-protected information. I find a bunch of semi-related documents, but they are all in C which is useless since I'm not using it.

Answer: R2, gets lowered in sInputStart and since I'm not reinitializing it, it prints a string length 0. Skipping it works fine.

Comment: That loos like it should work. As for the file descriptors they are unix conventions. 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr. You can open other files as needed.

Comment: The problem is the `POP {r1-r2, lr}` in your professor's code. The `lr` should be `pc` to make it return to the caller. With that change, it works here.

Comment: Calling conventions can be found at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#arm-32_bit_EABI.  For what the call actually does, `man 2 read`, or more general Unix programming information (e.g. the old but still excellent *Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment* books by Stevens).  All the official documentation is at the level of C, so you really do have to understand C a little bit to use Unix system calls, even if that's not the language you are actually coding in.

Comment: The system calls-related documentation is available [online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) as well. The documentation section numbering scheme is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean): `2      System Calls`